# Energy and momentum conservation laws in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

In special relativity the energy of a material point is defined
$$E= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}c^2,$$
and the momentum is defined by
$$\mathbb{p}=  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\mathbb{v},$$
where $\mathbb{v}$ is the velocity of the particle.

> I am wondering whether the conservation laws of energy and momentum in special relativity have been verified experimentally. At this point I would prefer avoiding quantum effects if possible.

Comment: Both energy and momentum are separately conserved in quantum field theory, which allows interactions that do not conserve particle number, so yes these conservation laws have been experimentally tested.

Comment: Experiments at the LHC confirm energy and momentum conservation every day the collider is running.

Comment: Thank you.  This is interesting.  If possible I would prefer classical rather than quantum situations.  And preferably as elementary as possible.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to ask what you really want to know. It talks about “particles”, which usually means subatomic particles. It does not mention classical or quantum physics. And it asks a question whose answer is either Yes or No.

Comment: @G.Smith : done.